# Input to array stopped by "quit " word

Tags: java, arrays, io

I need to do Football Results Generator. I created 4 arrays with 10 elements each, but I need to include a loop that allows the user to change their mind and stop input by typing "quit" after a certain number of entries. Could you please help - I am new to programming, so it must be dead simple.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//

public class Football_Results_Generator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);


        String[] HomeTeam = new String[10];
        String[] AwayTeam = new String[10];
        int[] HomeScore = new int[10];
        int[] AwayScore = new int[10];

        int index = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;

        do 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Home Team Name: ");
            HomeTeam[index] = kbd.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Away Team Name: ");
            AwayTeam[index] = kbd.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Home Team Score:");
            HomeScore[index] = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Away Team Score: ");
            AwayScore[index] = kbd.nextInt();
            kbd.nextLine();


        } while(index < 10);
        index = 0;

        System.out.println();   

        do 
        {
            System.out.println(HomeTeam[index] + " [" + HomeScore[index] + "]" + " | " + AwayTeam[index] + " [" + AwayScore[index] + "] ");
            index = index + 1;

        } while(index < 10);

        kbd.close();

        for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
            sum += HomeScore[index];
            for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
                sum1 += AwayScore[index];

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Totals");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total number of matches played: " + index);
        System.out.println("Total of all home scores: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Total of all away scores: " + sum1);
        System.out.println("Total number of draws: ");
        System.out.println("The highest home score: ");
        System.out.println("The highest away score: ");

    }
}
```

Comment: You'd like the user to be able to type "Quit" when asked for a team name and that would be the signal that he/she doesn't want to enter more teams?

Comment: What if there was a team called "Quit"?

Comment: @Seb what do you mean *after 5 tries*?

Comment: My example is array  with 10 elements  ....I am the user who input team names and scores  but  in meantime i decide i do not need to fill in whole 10  and i want only 5 elements  to be stored .that is  what i mean ...sorry guys i am new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

> allow user to change his mind and stop input by typing quit after 5 tries.

Use a temp variable to capture String input:

```
String line;
do 
{
    System.out.print("Enter Home Team Name: ");
    line = kbd.nextLine();
    if("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
        break;
    }
    HomeTeam[index] = line;
    .....
    index = index + 1; //missed
}while(index < 10);
index = 0;
```

Here, `"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)` will ensure that irrespctive of case of `line` e.g. "Quit","QUIT","quit",etc will result `true`

> What about integer input to array?? is it same concept ??

Well, you need to handle the exception in case input is neither `quit` nor `int`:

```
line = kbd.nextLine();
if("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
    break;
}
try{
    HomeScore[index] = new Integer(line);
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //Error conversion string to int
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help .Can you clarify  how it works with integer  as well?   can you comment code and explain  in you words what  equalsIgnoreCase(line) do  ?

Comment: thanks again for help   .What about integer input  to array?? is it same concept ??

Comment: From this what i know my next lesson will be about exception handling .. i will try this but i need to read about it so if i do demo and my teacher ask how it works  that i can answer his questions.thanks ...i will let you inow when i finish.